# Views 3: how to list users related to nodes category and exposed filter by that category

Tags: views

I need to list the node authors based on node category and also expose filter with that category. Can any one tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: "Users" , Do you mean author of the node ?

Comment: Yes. Distinct authors

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to solve the issue.

- Add relationship node author.
- In View Fields add field Node Author Name
- Add filter Node Category Field that is used to Categorize content.
- Expose the above filter
- Select Group By Node Author Name in View Style Settings so that you can see DISTINCT users belongs to Node Category

That should work i hope !

Comment: Thank you very much. I am having one more question? views 3 exposed filter with Hierarchical Select is there or not?